# The best way to transfer data from mobile

Tags: android, xml, json, http, restful-architecture

I want to develop client - server system (client is mobile). What the best way to transfer the data from server and to server? Using RESTful-architecture? HTTP requests? use JSON or XML?
If there isn't best way what is the advantages and disadvantages of each method?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very subjective question. You can use anything to transfer data to mobile devices, even a direct socket binary transfer. But as you have stated, one of the most popular methodologies is to use a REST-ful JSON interface. There are good libraries that support this system both on the client and server. The other option which is not as popular anymore is using XML/SOAP. Many people loathe XML/SOAP at this point, some don't mind. Of course, there are many others I will not mention.

As I stated before though, this is a subjective question. If I were to do this work, I would do REST/JSON, but it certainly is not the only way.

Comment: thanks for your comment!
have REST-ful JSON interface big overhead?

Comment: No, REST-ful JSON can be one of the most terse ways of transferring data. Of course, if you make the definitions overly complex and verbose, it won't be terse anymore.